# How to 3D print JavaFX 3D scene?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, blender, javafx-3d

I have been working on this scientific application in JavaFX. The program basically generates data from an algorithm and visualizes them into spheres that intersect. 
[image]

I would like to 3D print part of this model(the colored shapes). Is there a way exporting the JavaFX scene? Even if it means exporting it into a file such as .stl or .obj and importing into Blender for further refinement or file conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to export your 3D model to .obj you need to get access to the `TriangleMesh` of each shape, so you can export vertices and faces.

Currently, using built-in JavaFX 3D shapes like `Sphere`, this is not possible, since their meshes are not exposed.

Also, there is no built-in export method.

So the solution will be creating from the scratch your 3D shapes and providing an export method, or using third party solutions.

If you have a look at the F(X)yz [library](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz), it solves part of your problems, since it already provides:

- Several 3D shapes with full access to their meshes info
- Export to .obj and .mtl for any given 3D shape.

Unfortunately it doesn't allow for now exporting multiple shapes into one single .obj file, but that's something that can be easily added.

This is a quick implementation of a `Group` exporter, that will export all the `MeshView` in the group and their diffuse color to a single obj file and a single mtl file.

```
public class GroupOBJWriter {

    private final String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private float[] points0, texCoord0;
    private int[] faces0, sm0;
    private BufferedWriter writer = null;
    private final String fileName;
    private String diffuseMap;
    private String diffuseColor = "0.0 0.0 0.0"; // black
    private final Group group;

    public GroupOBJWriter(Group group, String fileName){
        this.group = group;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void exportMesh(){
        File objFile = new File(fileName + ".obj");
        try{
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(objFile));
            writer.write("mtllib " + fileName + ".mtl" + newline);

            AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger vCounter = new AtomicInteger();

            group.getChildren().stream()
                .filter(MeshView.class::isInstance)
                .map(s -> (TriangleMesh) ((MeshView) s).getMesh())
                .forEach(mesh -> {
                    try{
                        writer.write("# Material" + newline);
                        int count = counter.getAndIncrement();
                        writer.write("usemtl " + fileName + "-" + count + ""+newline);

                        points0 = new float[mesh.getPoints().size()];
                        mesh.getPoints().toArray(points0);
                        List<Point3D> points1 = IntStream.range(0, points0.length/3)
                            .mapToObj(i -> new Point3D(points0[3*i], points0[3*i+1], points0[3*i+2]))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                        writer.write("# Vertices (" + points1.size() + ") for shape " + count + "" + newline);
                        points1.forEach(p -> {
                            try {
                                writer.write("v " + p.x + " " + p.y + " " + p.z + "" + newline);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                System.out.println("Error writting vertex "+ex);
                            }
                        });
                        writer.write(newline);

                        texCoord0 = new float[mesh.getTexCoords().size()];
                        mesh.getTexCoords().toArray(texCoord0);

                        List<Point2D> texCoord1 = IntStream.range(0, texCoord0.length/2)
                                .mapToObj(i -> new Point2D(texCoord0[2*i], texCoord0[2*i+1]))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

                        writer.write("# Textures Coordinates (" + texCoord1.size() + ") for shape " + count + "" + newline);
                        texCoord1.forEach(t->{
                            try {
                                // objimporter u->u, v->(1-v)
                                writer.write("vt " + ((float) t.getX()) + " " + ((float) (1d - t.getY())) + "" +newline);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                System.out.println("Error writting texture coordinate " + ex);
                            }
                        });
                        writer.write(newline);

                        faces0 = new int[mesh.getFaces().size()];
                        mesh.getFaces().toArray(faces0);
                        List<Integer[]> faces1 = IntStream.range(0, faces0.length/6)
                                .mapToObj(i -> new Integer[]{faces0[6*i], faces0[6*i+1], 
                                    faces0[6*i+2], faces0[6*i+3], 
                                    faces0[6*i+4], faces0[6*i+5]})
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

                        writer.write("# Faces (" + faces1.size() + ") for shape " + count + "" + newline);
                        writer.write("# Material for shape " + count + "" + newline);
                        writer.write("usemtl " + fileName + "-" + count + "" + newline);
                        sm0 = new int[mesh.getFaces().size()];
                        mesh.getFaceSmoothingGroups().toArray(sm0);
                        if (sm0[0] > 0) {
                            writer.write("s " + sm0[0] + "" + newline);
                        }

                        AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
                        final int inc = vCounter.get() + 1;
                        faces1.forEach(f->{
                            try {
                                writer.write("f " + (f[0] + inc) + "/" + (f[1] + inc) +
                                              " " + (f[2] + inc) + "/" + (f[3] + inc) +
                                              " " + (f[4] + inc) + "/" + (f[5] + inc) + "" + newline);
                                if (sm0[c.getAndIncrement()] != sm0[c.get()]) {
                                    writer.write("s " + (sm0[c.get()] > 0 ? sm0[c.get()] : "off" ) + "" + newline);
                                }
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                System.out.println("Error writting face "+ex);
                            }
                        });
                        vCounter.addAndGet(points1.size());
                        writer.write(newline);
                    } catch(IOException io){
                        System.out.println("Error creating writer obj " + io);
                    }
                });
        } catch(IOException io){
             System.out.println("Error creating writer obj "+io);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(writer!=null){
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        File mtlFile = new File(fileName+".mtl");

        try{
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mtlFile));

            AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
            group.getChildren().stream()
                .filter(MeshView.class::isInstance)
                .map(s -> ((PhongMaterial) ((MeshView) s).getMaterial()).getDiffuseColor())
                .forEach(color -> {
                    try{
                        diffuseColor=""+((float)(color.getRed()))+" "+((float)(color.getGreen()))+" "+((float)(color.getBlue()));

                        int count = counter.getAndIncrement();
                        writer.write("# Material " + fileName + "-" + count + "" + newline);
                        writer.write("newmtl " + fileName + "-" + count + "" + newline);
                        writer.write("illum 4" + newline); // Illumination [0-10]
                        writer.write("Kd " + diffuseColor + "" + newline); // diffuse color black
                        writer.write("Ka 0.10 0.10 0.10" + newline); // ambient color
                        writer.write("Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00" + newline); // Transmission filter
                        if (diffuseMap != null) {
                            writer.write("map_Kd " + diffuseMap + "" + newline);
                        }
                        writer.write("Ni 1.00" + newline); // optical density
                        writer.write("Ks 1.00 1.00 1.00" + newline); // specular reflectivity
                        writer.write("Ns 32.00" + newline); // specular exponent
                        writer.write(newline);
                    } catch(IOException io){
                        System.out.println("Error creating writer obj " + io);
                    }
                });
        } catch(IOException io){
             System.out.println("Error creating writer mtl "+io);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(writer!=null){
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

With `SegmentedSphereMesh` from F(X)yz you can create a sphere, so this will be a sample of how to build a group and export them:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-20);
    Group sceneRoot = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot, 800, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene.setCamera(camera);
    Group group = new Group();

    for (int i = -5; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = -2; j < 2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                SegmentedSphereMesh sphere = new SegmentedSphereMesh(50, 0, 0, 0.75, new Point3D((float) i, (float) j, (float) k)); 

                sphere.setTextureModeNone(Color.rgb(255 / 10 * (6 + i), 255 / 5 * (j + 3), 255 / 3 * (k + 1)));
                group.getChildren().add(sphere);
            }
        }
    }

    group.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(40, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(10, Rotate.Y_AXIS));
    sceneRoot.getChildren().addAll(group);        

    primaryStage.setTitle("F(X)yz - Segmented Spheres Group");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();   

    GroupOBJWriter writer=new GroupOBJWriter(group,"spheres");
    writer.exportMesh();
}
```

[image: Group of spheres]

If you now import the resulting `spheres.obj` with [3DViewer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/fe6b492b9150/apps/samples/3DViewer) you'll see:

[image: 3DViewer]